# How to update a bound combo box after updates are made to database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox, sql-server-express

I have a SQL Server Express database containing medication info. I have created a windows form to display info on a selected medication. A combobox on the form is bound to the db using the following:

```
string sqlQuery = "select * from meds";
cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);

sqlDA.SelectCommand = cmd;
sqlDA.Fill(medsDT);

cboMeds.DataSource = medsDT;
cboMeds.DisplayMember = "medname";
cboMeds.ValueMember = "ID";
```

The form has a textbox ("adjAmt") that allows the user to change the 
quantity ("supply") of the selected med by entering the new quantity 
and clicking on a "change" button.

The database is updated with the following code:

```
SqlCommand cmdUpdate = new SqlCommand();
string cmdTxt = "Update meds set supply = '";
cmdTxt += adjAmt.ToString() + "' where ID = '";
cmdTxt += lblID.Text.ToString() + "';";
cmdUpdate.CommandText = cmdTxt;
cmdUpdate.Connection = conn;  
cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

At this point everything is working as designed, e.g. database is updated. After the update, I return the user to the form and expect to find the updated value on the form but it doesn't. Checking the database, I find the new "supply" value. I tried several options found on StackOverflow but none seem to work.

This should be a simple operation but for some reason, it isn't. Some of the options I've tried include clearing and reloading the combobox:

```
cboMeds.Datasource = null;
string sqlQuery = "select * from meds";
cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
sqlDA.SelectCommand = cmd;
sqlDA.Fill(medsDT);
cboMeds.DataSource = medsDT;
cboMeds.DisplayMember = "medname";
cboMeds.ValueMember = "ID";
```

This fails because there is a `SelectedIndexChanged` event which is triggered
when I try to change the `cboMeds.DataSource` property.  The event is setup to
repopulate the form when an item is selected in the combobox so when I try to delete the `cboMeds.DataSource`, it fires the event which throws an error:
"IndexOutOfRangeException" because there is nothing in the combobox after
setting the `combobox.DataSource` to null. Closing the form and then re-executing it resets the combobox as expected.

Isn't there a simple way to update the combobox when a bindingsource changes?

Comment: You should always use parameterized queries. This kind of string concatenations are open for SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Don't use `select *` - name the columns you need.

Comment: You could unregister the `SelectedIndexChanged` event before re-setting the data source then wire it back up after.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions on programming style (using parameters, and avoiding "SQL injection" issues).  These will be changed in due time. First priority is to get the app to function as desired.